# Check if value exist in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if values in Array1 exist in Array2. If it exist, then add the **index** for that value in a new array as a value.

My solution below is doing almost that but it dosent alert me every same number, duplicates. For exampel the value 4355 in array1, its 3 of that value, but it only alert me 1 time. I would like to alert me every time.

```
var array1 = [];
array1.push(3545);
array1.push(4355);     
array1.push(5435);
array1.push(3457); 
array1.push(4355);
array1.push(4355);
var array2 = [];
array2.push(1022);
array2.push(4355);
array2.push(2333);
array2.push(5656);
array2.push(1234);
array2.push(5555);
array2.push(7777);
array2.push(3455);

for(var i=0; i<array2.length; i++){
 checkIfExist(array2[i], array1);
}

function checkIfExist(searchValue, searchArray){
  if ($.inArray(searchValue, searchArray) < 0) {
      alert(searchValue + " not found");
    }
    else {
        alert(searchValue + " found with index(" + $.inArray(searchValue, array2) + ") in array");
    }
}
```

Comment: From your problem description it sounds like you're searching backwards. Your call to `checkIfExists` should be `checkIfExist(array1[1], array2);` You're only getting notified one time because 4355 only exists one time in array 2.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, thanks. But it dosent solve my problem with index, it gives the same index to every same value, but they have different indexes.

Comment: It looks like `array2` is supposed to be your 'reference' array - your lookup table to find indexes from. Since each number only appears once in `array2`, you'll always get the same index returned for each instance of the item in `array1`. If you're searching the other way around, and you want to find each instance of the number from `array2` in `array1`, then you need to modify `checkIfExist()` function to return an array of indexes.

Answer (score 2):

To find *all* the indices of a particular value in an array you could use `jQuery.each()`:

```
var indices = [];
$.each(searchArray, function(index, value) {
    if (value == searchValue) {
        indices.push(index);
    }
});
```

Now, `indices` is an array with the indices at which the value was found, or empty if there were no matches.

Comment: Very succinct and easy to understand. Using `$each()` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to well understand what you want... hope it will help you!

```js
var array1 = [];
array1.push(3545);
array1.push(4355);     
array1.push(5435);
array1.push(3457); 
array1.push(4355);
array1.push(4355);
var array2 = [];
array2.push(1022);
array2.push(4355);
array2.push(2333);
array2.push(5656);
array2.push(1234);
array2.push(5555);
array2.push(7777);
array2.push(3455);

var array3={};
for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
  if( (index= array2.indexOf(array1[i])) > 0 ){
    
    if(!array3[array1[i]])
      array3[array1[i]]= []
    array3[array1[i]].push({index1:i,index2:index});
    
  }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(array3, undefined, 2));
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try looping through the array and every time you find a match sending out the alert

```
alert(searchValue + " found with index(" + $.inArray(searchValue, array2) + ") in array");
```

(Sorry I couldn't put this as a comment, I don't have 50 reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular javascript way to get an index from an Array instead of these angular things:

```
array.indexOf( value )
```

This will return the index of the value, or `-1` if it is not found.

```
function checkIfExist(value, array) {
  var index = array.indexOf(value);

  if (index === -1) {
    alert(searchValue + " not found");
  } else {
    alert(value + " found with index(" + index + ") in array");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xw390r8/1):

```
var arr = [3545, 4355, 5435, 3457, 4355, 4355],
arr2 = [1022, 4355, 2333, 5656, 1234, 5555, 7777, 3455],
occurences = {};

arr2.forEach(function(el, i, array) {
    occurences[el] = $.map(arr, function(element, index) {
        return element == el ? index : null;
    });
});

console.log(occurences);

$('body').html('Indexes: '+JSON.stringify(occurences));

// ==> Indexes: {"1022":[],"1234":[],"2333":[],"3455":[],"4355":[1,4,5],"5555":[],"5656":[],"7777":[]}
```

Basically, this loops through `arr2` to match each of those values to a value in `arr`.  Each value from `arr2` is made a key to a new object, called `occurences`, and there is an array of the indexes of `arr` where the values match the ones that are in `arr2`.

As you can see, the only value from `arr2` that appears in `arr` is **4355**, and it occurs at the indexes of **1, 4, and 5**. Since none of the other values from `arr2` match those in `arr`, the arrays of indexes for those values are simply empty.

Obviously you can pretty the code up a bit and adjust it as it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`$.inArray` gives the index only for the first occurrence in array starting from `0` else `-1`.

```
function checkIfExist(searchValue, searchArray){
  var index = [];//trace all matching index
  for(var i = 0, l = searchArray.length; l > i; i ++) {
    if(searchValue === searchArray[i]) {//matched value
      index.push(i);//add index to array
    }
  }
  return index;
}

var arr = checkIfExist(0, [1,0,3,9,0]);

if(arr.length) {//match found
    alert('Matched at index: ' + arr.join(','))
} else {
  alert('No match found');
}
```